# How to do dict calculations and insert into another optimized dict in python

Tags: python, dictionary

The idea is as follows: I have three dicts (`dict1, dict2, dict3`) in which I need to perform a calculation and insert the result in another dict (`dict4`), note:

```
dict1 = {'aaa': 50, 'bbb': 20, 'ccc': 60}
dict2 = {'aaa': 10, 'bbb': 10, 'ccc': 10}
dict3 = {'aaa': 2, 'bbb': 2, 'ccc': 3}
```

The calculation to be inserted in `dict4` is:

```
dict4 = {'aaa': 2.5, 'bbb': 1, 'ccc': 2}
```

where:

For each element equal:

```
'aaa' => 50 / (10 * 2) = 2.5

'bbb' => 20 / (10 * 2) = 1

'ccc' => 60 / (10 * 3) = 2
```

I got the expected result, look at my code;

```py
for i,j in dict4.items():
    for x,y in dict1.items():
        for k,w in dict2.items():
            for a,b in dict3.items():
                if i==x and i==k and i==a:
                    dict4[i] = y/(w*b)
```

but I believe it is not the best form. Does anyone have a more optimized idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have same keys in all 3 dicts you don't have to itereate over each of them, just use `dict-comprehension` like below.

```
dict4 = {k: dict1[k]/(dict2[k]*dict3[k]) for k in dict1}

print(dict4)
```

Output:

```
{'aaa': 2.5, 'bbb': 1.0, 'ccc': 2.0}
```